# Why does this JUnit assertion fail if method executed on same line?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a simple JUnit test. It fails, unless I have called the relevant function previously.

**FAILS:**

```
@Test public void isTotalSuccess(){
    writer.calculateStats();
    Assert.assertFalse(writer.isTotalSuccess());
}
```

**PASSES** and displays "TotalSuccess is false":

```
@Test public void isTotalSuccess(){
    writer.calculateStats();
    // One additional line here
    System.out.println("TotalSuccess is " + writer.isTotalSuccess());
    Assert.assertFalse(writer.isTotalSuccess());
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since usually nested methods/functions are evaluated first, before their enclosing function.

**Please explain why the test fails unless the method being tested has already been called once.** Is this behaviour specific to JUnit, or have I missed something really obvious?

---

More information:

These tests are part of `WriterTest`, which is testing `Writer`

`writer` is declared as a field of `WriterTest` with `private static Writer writer = new Writer();`

`writer.isTotalSuccess()` is a very simple method:

```
public boolean isTotalSuccess() {
    if (total == success){
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is `==` applicable for `total` and `success`, i.e. are they primitive types, or should you be using `.equals()`?

Comment: Does `isTotalSuccess` still fail if you delete all other tests?